# Handling multiple forms in spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tabs, contextmenu

In my jsp i am having multiple tabs containing separate forms,see below image:

[image]

Problem:
Since all tabs are present in same JSP, it is reached up to 1300 lines. which can not be neglected.

Since I am using spring mvc,I need to bind all 4 objects(ABC,ABC SUB1,ABC SUB2,ABC SUB3) while returning view, which is also not acceptable.

I am thinking of dividing this whole page into 4 different jsp's (and including jsp's based on the requirement or event), but still not satisfied with my solution.

Can any body give me any other solutions...????

Thanks .....!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax to submit only for you need at once.